# Total possible ways of representing n! as a sum of two or more consecutive positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, prime-factorization

I need to calculate total possible ways of representing $n!$ as a sum of two or more consecutive positive integers.

**Example** : $3!=1*2*3=6$ and $6=1+2+3$ the only **one** possible way.

**Answer** : $1$

The approach I followed is as follows:

Let $p≤N$ be a **prime**. The highest power of $p$ dividing $N$ is given by $α_p=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{N}{p^k} \rfloor$

so $N! = 2^{\alpha_2}3^{\alpha_3}5^{\alpha_5} \ldots p^{\alpha_q}$ where $q$ the last prime $\leq N$

We want $N!=a+(a+1)+(a+2)+(a+3)+\ldots +(a+n)=\frac{(2a+n)(n+1)}{2}$ where $a,n\ge 1$ where $a,n \in \mathbb{I} $

Hence equating the above two equations we get, $2^{\alpha_2}3^{\alpha_3}5^{\alpha_5} \ldots p^{\alpha_q}=\frac{(2a+n)(n+1)}{2}$

So finally , $2^{(\alpha_2+1)}3^{\alpha_3}5^{\alpha_5} \ldots p^{\alpha_q}={(2a+n)(n+1)}$ , for the above examle $2^2 3^1=(2*2+2)(2+1)$ so $a=2$ and $n=2$

I am not able to proceed further because **brute force** solution is just not enough.I found the [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18567/determine-in-how-many-ways-n-can-be-expressed-as-sum-of-consecutive-numbers?rq=1) but the solutions provided are not leading to exact solution of the problem.How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Let $n!=N=2^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_t^{a_t}$ where $a_0\ge 0$ and the $p_i$ are distinct odd primes. Then the number of ways is $(a_1-1)\cdots (a_t+1)-1$. The $a_i$ can be cheaply determined once we know the $p_i$, by an algorithm that is likely familiar to you. So for example for $4!$ there is $1$ way, for $5!$ there are $2$, for $6!$ there are $6$, for $7!$ there are $12$, for $8!$ there are $12$, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$a=\frac{N!}{n+1}-\frac{n}{2}$$

So, you can find the solutions as follows :

- Find the divisors of $2N!$ , excluding $1$.
- For each such divisor $d$, calculate $e\ :=\ \frac{N!}{d}-\frac{d-1}{2}$
- If the result is a positive integer, the pair $[e,d-1]$ is a solution.

Since the divisors of a factorial can be determined efficiently, this
method solves the problem efficiently.